# Check if several values have changed in reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have some fields in reactive forms that I have to check if values have changed. I know how to check if value have changed on one field like this

```
this.form.controls['phone'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  data => console.log('form changes', data)
  );
```

The problem I have is that I need to check two or more fields, e.g. phone and address.

Comment: Subscribe to the whole form's valueChanges, instead of one control's?

Comment: That is the point, i have some fields that i dont need to check, thats why i can not subscribe to entire form changes

Comment: Why *"can not"*? Just filter out what you're not interested in. Or have separate observables for the separate controls and join them back together.

Comment: This is not point why I 'can not', i have tried to make simple question to understand

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. If you can do that, why haven't you? If you've tried that and it doesn't work, give a [mcve] to illustrate, but there was no point showing something that definitely won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can merge observables, but it merges into a single observable, i.e.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

merge(
  this.form.controls['phone'].valueChanges,
  this.form.controls['address'].valueChanges
).subscribe(console.log)
```

alternatively you can use combineLatest. Which will emit the latest value from each observable. I think this is what you need.

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

combineLatest(
  this.form.controls['phone'].valueChanges, 
  this.form.controls['address'].valueChanges
).subscribe((phone, address) => {
  // do something
})
```